# What layer does the logic of displaying what is possible in a many-to-many relationship belong in a Web UI / REST API / Database application?

Tags: rest, web

I've written a report that displays all of the possible combinations between two lists (it's a grid with columns from one list, and a grid of columns from another list).  It forms a spreadsheet like structure and places an X in cells where the two lists have a many-to-many relation.

Of course it's paired down with categories and there is a limit to the number of items that can be in a category, as these sorts of queries are frowned upon for a good reason since the number of items in both lists multipled by one another result in the number of possible cells that fall between.  Also note that this is a small database, and not one that's to be used by many people at one time (SQLite3).

I've already got the logic to display it, by querying the tables, and their weak entity, the output even comes back out as expected; but now I'm trying to clean up the code, and wondering where to place the logic for this given that I'd like to use a REST API between the database and the web frontend.

Should the front-end query the REST API for the necessary values, and then string them together into a report, or should the REST API do that and just return JSON for the table in the report to the front end so that it can be processed into an HTML table?  It also seems to me that maybe I need a backend API layer that hooks into REST API to keep that decoupled as well, but it almost feels like too much.

Comment: How can you have a rep of 8k and not know that this question is both "too broad" and "primarily opinion based"?

Comment: @bhspencer Alright shoot the question over to the Programmers Stackexchange.  I'd like to hear some opinions.

Comment: Programmers.SE is not for opinion polls. We have the same "too broad" and "primarily opinion based" close reasons as every other SE site.

Comment: @lxrec That's a function of the SE software, and all the sites have that.  The Programmers.SE was actually opened up for questions like this.  I just posted to the wrong one.  Think about it; does it really make any sense to have a Stackoverflow and a Programmers.SE?

Comment: @leeand00 [That's a very long story](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/279182), but the short version is we stopped being SO's "toilet bowl" years ago after the powers that be declared that experiment a failure. Whether the result makes any sense is something to take up on meta (though many, many before you have made that argument already).

Comment: @Ixrec well then according to your logic; you're site doesn't deserve to exist.  Maybe you need to lay off the coffee and switch to decaf.

Comment: [Difference between Programmers and StackOverflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow) - [Six Subjective question guidelines](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice)

Comment: I think you could do this either way.  Do you have any criteria for choosing between the two methods?  Performance?  Flexibility of the API?  [Resistance to butterfly wings?](https://xkcd.com/378/)